# append the element in xml c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have write the xml through following code as

```
 if (!File.Exists("d:\\s.xml"))
 {    
     XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("d:\\s.xml", null);
     textWriter.WriteStartDocument();
     textWriter.WriteStartElement("node");    
     textWriter.WriteStartElement("zone");    
     textWriter.WriteStartElement("dt");    
     textWriter.WriteStartElement("Mn");
     textWriter.WriteString("m1");
     textWriter.WriteEndElement();    
     textWriter.WriteStartElement("Dist");
     textWriter.WriteString("Colony");
     textWriter.WriteEndElement();   
     textWriter.WriteEndElement();
     textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
     textWriter.Close();
 }
```

which gives the output as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Node>
    <Zone>
        <Dt>
            <mn>m1</mn>
            <Dist>Colony</Dist>
        </Dt>
    </Zone>
</Node>
```

Now i need to append  the  following xml to already exist xml file

```
<Dt1>
    <mn>m1</mn>
    <Dist>Colony</Dist>
</Dt1>
```

Comment: `I have tried many samples but not succeed.` What are those `samples`?

Comment: Any reason why you're using `XmlTextWriter` in particular? It's much harder to use than loading the existing document into LINQ to XML, editing it, then saving.

Comment: @JonSkeet ya will have to do that only

Comment: @JonSkeet say some other ideas other than using xml textwriter

Comment: if suitable you can use object serialization and deserialization.

Comment: @Jodha can u provide me any samples for it

Comment: @GowthamanSS: Um, I did in the comment...

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer using Linq2Xml

```
var xml = new XElement("Node",
                new XElement("Zone",
                        new XElement("Dt", 
                                new XElement("mn1", "m1"), 
                                new XElement("Dist", "Colony") 
                            )
                    )
                );

var str1 = xml.ToString();

xml.Descendants("Zone")
    .First()
    .Add(new XElement("Dt1",
                new XElement("mn1", "m1"), 
                new XElement("Dist", "Colony")));

var str2 = xml.ToString();

xml.Save(filename);
```

Comment: But OP wants to add that in an already created file.

Comment: Then replace the first part with `XElement.Load`. I just wanted to show how to use Linq2Xml to form an xml

Comment: In that case +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get where do you want to add the next node, but my guess is you want to keep the structure of the XML file you posted. If that is the case, and expanding Jon Skeet's answer, you can do that with XElement:

```
var zone = new XElement(
            "Zone",
            new XElement(
                "Dt",
                new XElement("Mn", "m1"),
                new XElement("Dist", "Colony")));

        var xml = new XElement("Node", zone);

        // append new nodes here
        zone.FirstNode.AddAfterSelf(
            new XElement(
                "Dt",
                new XElement("Mn", "m1"),
                new XElement("Dist", "Colony")));

        // save file
        xml.Save("d:\\s.xml");
```

Comment: at first we are writing in xml during second time i need to add new tag thats it